# NodeJS CSV Parse library removes " in JSON

Tags: node.js

I am using the Nodejs Library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-csv

I am trying to read in a CSV file that has JSON strings between the delimiters.  The problem is, using this library, it removes the double quotes from around the key and value which means when I try and run JSON.parse() over the JSON string it fails.

The file contains:
12345678,'{"test":"help me"}','{"this does not": "work"}'

And upon interpreting the file, it turns it into:

12345678,'{test:help me}','{this does not: work}'

Any idea how to stop it removing the double quotes?

Comment: I looked at their NPM readme and it didn't mention anything about it. But I then looked at their source code on GitHub (by following the link from NPM) and they do say something interesting in the file `https://github.com/anton-bot/async-csv/blob/master/index.ts`: "The quote characters, defaults to the ", an empty quote value will preserve the original field." So it looks like you can provide config to specify that it keep the quote characters inside each field.

Answer (score 0):

There's the `relax` option which you can set to `true` and it will preserve quotes inside unquoted field. You can then manually replace the single quotes and parse the json:

```
// ...
const rows = await csv.parse(csvString, {relax: true});

rows[0].forEach(r => {
    let rawValue = r.replace(/'/g, '');
    console.log(`raw value: ${rawValue}, parsed value: ${JSON.parse(rawValue)}`);
});
```

Applied to your input, above code will print:

```
raw value: 12345678, parsed value: 12345678
raw value: {"test":"help me"}, parsed value: [object Object]
raw value: {"this does not": "work"}, parsed value: [object Object]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I should have shared my code, because I already have the relax:true set and it is still removing all the quotes inside of the JSON!

dataAr = await csv.parse(file, {delimiter: delimiter, relax: true, escape: fileEscape, quote: fileQuote, skip_empty_lines: true});

Comment: Hmm, have you tried my exact code? The `relax` option is only part of the solution, you need to manually replace the single quotes.